# Window Resize Event, and Add and Clear Google Map Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, debouncing

I'm running into an issue on Chrome in Windows 10 when initializing a sequence of functions, which is initially triggered by the window resize event. The sequence of events can be summarized as such:

1. The window resize event calls
2. `initializeMap()` which calls
3. `codeAddress()` which calls
4. `retrieveAndCompareBounds()` which calls
5. `clearMarkers()` which calls
6. `dropMarkers()` which calls
7. `dropMarkersWithTimeout()`

The code works fine **unless** somebody either **(a) manually resizes the browser** or **(b) presses the shrink browser button** since both of those "events" always trigger at least two window resize events in quick succession, whereby duplicate markers are somehow added to the array of markers **after** the `clearMarkers()` clears the markers from the map and then empties the array.

I'd thought of a couple solutions, which were:

- I moved `clearMarkers()` above `dropMarkers()` in the hierarchy, which did not appropriately address the issue because the event was being fired at least twice in quick succession.
- Splitting the sequence of functions between `retrieveAndCompareBounds()` and `clearMarkers()`, and then adding the event listener `map.addListener('idle', clearMarkers)`, which has the same erroneous effect because it seems multiple Google Map `idle` events are fired.
- In desperation I tried using the `onmouseup` event, which obviously cannot be detected outside of the window.

In my search for a solution I have read about [debouncing and throttling](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) the resize event. Debouncing — about which more info can be found [here](https://john-dugan.com/javascript-debounce/) — appeared to be the solution. However, although implementing debouncing certainly improves issue by a large extent, the issue still persits if one resizes the browser after the debounce function is called but before `dropMarkers()` / `dropMarkersWithTimeout()` have completed.

**I'm wondering if there is an actual solution to this issue nowadays?**

P.S. I haven't included the code because it's quite extensive. Despite that, I will gladly post the code, or a compressed version thereof, if somebody requests that I do so.

Answer (score 0):

So guess you've identified two issues...

1. Too many function calls on resize
2. Synchronicity

You're right about debounce, you can use something like [resizilla](https://github.com/julienetie/resizilla) 
to manage this, it also helps with the change of orientation in mobile that also triggers window resize.

To keep the function calls in order you can use a [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) lib such as [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/). You may need to rebuild your functions to return arguments to be passed down to the next [thenables](https://promisesaplus.com/) :

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setImmediate(function(){
     resolve(initializeMap());
  });
  // or
  // reject ("Error!");
});

p1.then(function(value) {
  return codeAddress(value); // the return of initializeMap
}, function(value) {
  return retrieveAndCompareBounds(value);
}),
...
```

You can use [setImmediate](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate) or setTimeout(fn,0) within the "Promise" as a timing function wrapper.